# How to configure driver in Buildroot for Moxa UPort 1110 USB serial converter?

Tags: linux, serial-port, embedded, buildroot

I have a board with an embedded system that is buildroot based. In "make linux-menuconfig" I would like to add the appropriate drivers for the USB-RS232 adapter "Moxa UPORT 1110". I marked in "make linux-menuconfig":

```
Device Drivers-> USB support -> USB Serial Converter support-> USB MoxaUPORT Serial Driver
```

after connecting the adapter with the device, linux will not recognize the device.

When I check "lsusb" I get:

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 110a:1110
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002
```

The board does not see the producer's name etc. On my Ubuntu computer I get after plugging in usb and typing "lsusb ::

```
Bus 001 Device 036: ID 110a:1110 Moxa Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

When I check dmesg after plugging in the USB and see:

```
[ 9752.822985] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 9754.605939] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using musb-hdrc
[ 9754.768212] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=110a, idProduct=1110
[ 9754.775263] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 9754.782783] usb 1-1: Product: UPort 1110
[ 9754.786903] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Moxa Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

should I check any additional settings / drivers in "make linux-menuconfig" to see the USB-R232 adapter?

Answer (score 2):

From looking at the Linux source code, I understand that you enabled the `mxuport` driver which does not cover the UPORT 1110. However, it looks like the `ti_usb_3410_5052` driver does. You can enable it by setting `CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_TI`.

In the Buildroot sources I see that you must make sure that `BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_USB_SERIAL_TI` is set in order to include the firmware file (`moxa-1110.fw`).

So, in `make menuconfig` enable `USB TI 3410/5052 Serial Firmware` under `Target packages > Hardware handling > Firmware > linux-firmware > USB to Serial Firmware`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When I used "lsmod" i get only "ipv6". In buildroot "make linux-menuconfig" i found and set variable "CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_TI" but I cant find "BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_USB_SERIAL_TI" in "make menuconfig". Do you know whats the path to set this variable? I have to use GUI, I cant use something like nano.

Comment: I've extended my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, the path you have provided "Target packages > Hardware handling > Firmware > linux-firmware > USB to Serial Firmware"  is not any "USB to Serial Firmware". I found similar one in "Device Drivers > USB support > USB Serial Converter support > USB TI 3410/5052 Serial Driver ", but still doesn't bind moxa to the USB port. I noticed that after connecting the cable to the port, the "Active" LED does not light up. When I connect to another computer, it starts to glow. I tried to plug in another USB-RS232 cable to my port and it detects it

Comment: I've added some screenshots. Which version of Buildroot are you using?